# Dimensions of vectors in dot-product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

As far as I know, if we use the dotproduct for two vectors a,b with each having the dimension d x 1, we have to take the transpose of one of the vectors, i.e.  $\vec{a}^T*\vec{b}$. However, I often see that the tranpose is not taken. For instance the notation $||a||^2 = \vec{a}*\vec{a}$ is used. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$||a||^2 = \vec{a}^T*\vec{a} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} = \langle \vec{a}, \vec{a}\rangle\,$ where "$*$" stands for [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Row_vector_and_column_vector), and "$\cdot$" or "$\langle,\rangle$" stand for [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Definition). Those would normally be specified in contexts where there is any risk of ambiguity.

Comment: Hence for the dot product, the vectors need to have the same dimensions, whereas for the matrix product the dimensions have to be according to matrix multipliciation, correct? However, if defined, for vectors both have the same result?

Comment: What is confusing me, is that in linear regression contexts, the transpose is being used (see here beta): $ (Y - X\beta)^{T}(Y-X\beta) + \lambda \beta^T\beta.$

Comment: @TestGuest `if defined, for vectors both have the same result` That's correct. `in linear regression contexts, the transpose is being used` That's customary in contexts where matrix multiplication is to be assumed by default.

Comment: I think that it should also be mentioned that vectors are normally not thought of as matrices. Of course it's only when they are represented as matrices that matrix multiplication and taking transpose makes sense.

Comment: @md2perpe In some contexts it is relatively common to work with row vectors and column vectors considered as matrices, and represent the dot product as matrix multiplication [$a \cdot b = a^T b = b^T a$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors#Operations).

Comment: @xdiv In some contexts, yes. But in many contexts not so. I think that I've mostly seen it in numerical analysis and discretization.